# Adding up multiple data frames based on 2 unique identifiers

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have ten data frames and I would like to add up them based on id and pnum. What is the best way to do this? Thank you

df1  -example of df1

```
id pnum v1  v2  v3... v144
111 1   1    0   0 ... 0  
111 2   1    1   0  ...0
121 1   1    1   0  ...0
123 2   1    1   0  ...0
123 1   1    1   0  ...0



df3 -example of df3

id pnum v1  v2  v3... v144
111 1   0    0   0 ... 0  
111 2   0    0   0  ...1
121 1   0    0   0  ...1
123 2   0    0   0  ...0
123 1   0    0   0  ...1

...

df10 -example of df10

id pnum v1  v2  v3... v144
111 1   0    0   0 ... 0  
111 2   0    1   0  ...1
121 1   0    0   1  ...1
123 2   0    1   0  ...0
123 1   0    0   0  ...1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the datasets in a `list` with `mget`, use `bind_rows` to row bind the datasets to a single dataset, grouped by 'id', 'pnum', summarise all the columns (`summarise_all`) to return the `sum` for each group

```
library(dplyr)
mget(paste0('df', 1:10)) %>%
   bind_rows %>%
   group_by(id, pnum) %>%
   summarise_all(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `rbind` on list of data frames and then run `aggregate`

```
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3, ..., df10)

master_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)

agg_df <- aggregate(. ~ ID + pnum, master_df, sum)
```